# showing crash information in vxworks 5.4

Tags: c, vxworks

All, I am woring on embedded system running on vxworks 5.4. Here I am writing a code in existing 
huge code base. I am installed handled for various exceptions and I can see my exceptions caught.

I am following text on console. I want to know what is API used by vxworks to print this 
information so that I can search for API in code base. Any inputs how to print this information
if there is no direct API supported by vxworks 5.4

```
Illegal Instruction (Error on Instruction Fetch)
Program Counter: 0x00000000
Status Register: 0x3004
Format         : 0x04
Fault Status   : 0x4
Task: 0x27fe908 "tConfig"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note sure of your intent, but you can check excArchShow.c specific to your target (MIPS/PPC etc) in vxworks 5.5.1. It implements vxworks exception facilities.